# How to perform modification on the components of one react app which can be reflected into another react app

Tags: reactjs, components, hadoop-yarn, rollup, rollupjs

How to perform modifications on the components of one react app which can be reflected into another react-app (main) in which the previous app has been integrated.

Suppose I have two react apps, one is called **components-ui** and the other one is called **main-frontend-ui**. The **components-ui** is integrated in the **main-frontend-ui** react app so that it can access all of the former react app's components.

Now, I want to perform some modifications on the **components-ui** app, but I want the changes to be reflected on the **main-frontend-ui** app.

The issue is that even though I'm making changes in the **components-ui**, I don't see those changes being reflected in the **main-frontend-ui**.

I have tried doing `yarn-rollup` in the **components-ui** app, and then **copy** the **dist folder** from **components-ui** app and **paste** it in the **node-modules of main-frontend-ui** app, and then restarting the server using `yarn start:dev`, but still nothing is working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The probably unhelpful but actually correct answer would be: You don't do it.

You should treat 2 separate apps like 2 separate projects. However, if the two projects are going to interface or share code, I think the cleaner way would probably be to deal with git submodules, if you use git (which you should at this point).

You can learn more about it [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)